# How to check out the previous tag on a specific branch?

Tags: git

Our automated installation script is supposed to work like this:

1. clone some specific tag
2. run the installation script
3. if something goes wrong, run the rollback script

The rollback script is supposed to work like this:

1. run some rollback subscripts
2. **check out the previous tag from `production` branch**
3. run some subscripts from the previous release

How can I do the bolded part? I know how to get the previous *commit* (~1), but how to get the one that was tagged?

Comment: Check the tags with ```git tag```. It's not like they are numbered or anything where you could set up a formula for it. If you were installing v1.5.6, perhaps you should check for tag v1.5.5? And then it would be ```git checkout v1.5.5```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 <commit>` will give you the most recent tag from the commit.

Comment: Looks like `git checkout \`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --first-parent CURRENTTAG^\`` is the command I need

Comment: Why is the answer in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some sort of convention to make this work.  So far you know that you want to find a tag reachable from a branch, and that it should be the first tag you find (not counting the one for the current release? not clear to me if that one is reachable from `production`... but anyway...)

That's not enough to go on for git.

One solution would be to always have a specific tag on the "previous release".  Rollback step 2 would do `git checkout prev_release`, and release step 4 would be "if we didn't roll back, move the `prev_release` tag".

Or if your build server keeps its repo around and always has it checked out to the most recent production release, then you could use the reflog.  `git checkout -`.  If you're re-cloning before checking out the tag for the new release, this won't work.  (Unclear to me because you said "clone some specific tag", which is imprecise language.  You *check out* a specific tag, which you might do with the `-b` option of `clone`.)

Or if your tag names follow a pattern, you could calculate the previous tag name (but generally this isn't a reliable idea if the tags are version numbers).

Or if you use something like gitflow, where every commit on your production branch is a release, you can just say `production` (or `production^` if you've already merged the new release).  This is one of the very nice things about gitflow.

Comment: The second tag is a neat idea! But it won't work if we have to rollback post-hoc, if the installation was technically successful.

Comment: If you have to roll back post-hoc, it doesn't have to be a fully automated process.  "Hey, the automated scripts said we passed, but something's wrong.  We need to roll back.  Go re-tag version 1.37.2_b as `prev_release` and run the rollback scripts."